# Parameterizing a line that passes through points

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric, parametrization

I've been having a lot of trouble. I know you have to set up an equation where f(15)=P and f(17)=Q, but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image: problem]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line in general has the equation 
$$r(t)=a+t b,$$
where $a=(a_1,a_2)$ is the initial point and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ is the direction. You want that $r(15)=(4,2)$ and $r(17)=(11,9)$, i.e., that
$$\begin{cases}(a_1+15b_1,a_2+15b_2)=(4,2)\\(a_1+17b_1,a_2+17b_2)=(11,9).\end{cases}$$

Comparing the first entries gives two simultaneous equations for $a_1$ and $b_1$, and comparing the second entries gives the same for $a_2$ and $b_2$. Solving these simultaneous equations gives that $a=-\tfrac12(97,101)$ and $b=\tfrac72(1,1)$, so the line is
$$\boxed{r(t)=\tfrac12(7t-97,7t-101)}$$

Comment: Thank you I finally get it! You're a life-saver! @LukeCollins

Comment: No problem @Alex.G, I have some [short notes](https://drmenguin.com/files/vectors.pdf) on solving these sorts of problems if you would like to go through them.

Answer (score 1):

A line is parametrized in the following way:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now we know that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}+15
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
11 \\
9
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}+17
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
11 \\
9
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From which we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3.5 \\
3.5
\end{bmatrix}$$
So now we can write our line in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
3.5 \\
3.5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Substituting either $P$ or $Q$ we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}+15
\begin{bmatrix}
3.5 \\
3.5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we conclude that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-48.5 \\
-50.5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the parametrization of our line is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-48.5 \\
-50.5
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
3.5 \\
3.5
\end{bmatrix}
$$